# php date function gives me the same time over and over again

Tags: php, date, time

I used this code to display the timezone and today's date in `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm` :

```php
$timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
echo "The current server timezone is: " . $timezone . "<br/>";
$tod = date('m/d/Y h:m a');
echo $tod;
```

and I've set the timezone before so it displays the correct one, but every time I open the page in gives me 20/7/2019 1:07 pm, like the time never updates, I tried to change my server from wamp but still not updating..
anyone knows how can I solve it?

**EDIT:** 
I found out something that makes it more specific, it does update the hour, but the minute is stuck at 07, what would be the right way to make it behave right?

Comment: Have you tried with simply `<?php echo date(); ?>` nothing else.... then let me know what is output..

Comment: @KaushaMehta so I did it, and it displayed 2:07 pm, when the time now is 2:00 pm, and it also updated the first result too so now both display 2:07

Comment: what is your system time and the output time? check both at the same time then let me know.

Comment: @KaushaMehta my system time is 2:09 now, but the output is still on 2:07

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after re-checking the manual after specifying what the problem really is with, I found out that h:m is not right, because `m` represents `the month` not the minute, for minutes you have to put `i`.
so if you want something like:
dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm am/pm
you should use:

```php
$todays_date = date('d/m/Y h:i a');
```

note: many tutorials has it as `h:m`, so always consider reading the manual:  [PHP: date - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to have something to do with browser cache. Prepend your code with this:

```php
header("cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
```

And then clear your browser cache (this is important, otherwise, your new HTTP headers won't even reach the browser).

Comment: cleared cache, added the headers, tried another browser, another server, still not updating the time